# ConcurrentIdentityWeakKeyHashMap and Integer keys

Tags: java, integer, hashmap, netty, internal

Though internal, I presumed that it is safe to use ConcurrentIdentityWeakKeyHashMap generally. However, the following code:

```
ConcurrentIdentityWeakKeyHashMap map = new ConcurrentIdentityWeakKeyHashMap();
for(int key = 0;  key < 132; key++){
     map.put(key, key);
 }
for(int key = 0;  key < 132; key++){
     System.out.println(map.get(key));
 }
```

produces:

```
0
1
..
124
125
126
127
null
null
null
null
```

Is this a bug or a misconception on my side (i.e. "shouldn't be used with Integers" or "internal use only")?

EDIT: based on Lucianos comments, I altered the code a bit to make it hold a reference to the (I hope at least) very same Integer in the list and in the map:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(132);
 ConcurrentIdentityWeakKeyHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentIdentityWeakKeyHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
 for(int key = 0;  key < 132; key++){
     Integer key2 = key;
     list.add(key2);
     map.put(key2, key2);
 }
 for(int key = 0; key < 132; key++){
     System.out.println(map.get(list.get(key)));
 }
```

Now, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer up to 127 are precached in the Integer class, so they will never be garbage collected.

Comment: OK, so what's the point then? Did you mean to say that values with keys up to 127 are never GCed and everything above is GCed instantly?

Comment: Also, it uses identity ( == ) to compare keys, so when you do get(key), the autoboxing creates a new Integer object with the key number, but that object is different than the one saved on the Map, so the identity equals operator returns false, therefore you get a null value.